# Create app for customer

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

Is it possible to create a app and sell it to multiple customer?
My intention is to create a generel app and then customize that app and sell it. 
Then customer can buy that app. 
And if the company is called ABC and the app is called myApp, then the app is called ABCmyApp

And a second question. 
Is it posible for me to submit all the customers app so its my name on the app store?

Thank
Jakob

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed **possible.**

If the *generic* app of yours won't change in any aspect *(logic nor interface)* between the different customers, you could just use different **Targets** in Xcode. In each **Target** you'll be able to set different names and use different **Provisioning Profiles** to publish the App.

In the same way, if all the **Provisioning Profiles** you'd be using were of your developer account, the showing name in the *App Store* would be yours.

Comment: Thanks :) do you know how many of these app i will be able to publish on one account? If there is a limit

Comment: @user2999692 As far as I know, there's no limit.